# problem in defining margins in a page

Tags: spacing

I am using JHEP text template. Here one problem I am facing, the space is too wide and blanck at the foot of each page. I tried to change all the values, related to margin at foot but still I can not write at the bottom. It is keeping the space.
[image]

I am attaching the style file

```
%% Copyright 2013 SISSA Medialab
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
% The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
% version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status `author-maintained'.
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work is
% SISSA Medialab <info@medialab.sissa.it>
%
% This work consists of the file jheppub.sty.
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{jheppub}[2018/12/04 v.1.1227]


\gdef\@fpheader{Prepared for submission to JHEP}
\gdef\@journal{jhep}

\newif\ifnotoc\notocfalse
\newif\ifemailadd\emailaddfalse
\newif\iftoccontinuous\toccontinuousfalse
\newif\ifnatbibsort\natbibsorttrue

\DeclareOption{no-natbib-sort}{\natbibsortfalse}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\RequirePackage{epsfig}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\ifnatbibsort\RequirePackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}\else\RequirePackage[numbers,compress]{natbib}\fi
\RequirePackage[colorlinks=true
  ,urlcolor=blue
  ,anchorcolor=blue
  ,citecolor=blue
  ,filecolor=blue
  ,linkcolor=blue
  ,menucolor=blue
  ,linktocpage=true
  ,pdfproducer=medialab
  ,pdfa=true
]{hyperref}

\def\@subheader{\@empty}
\def\@keywords{\@empty}
\def\@abstract{\@empty}
\def\@xtum{\@empty}
\def\@dedicated{\@empty}
\def\@arxivnumber{\@empty}
\def\@collaboration{\@empty}
\def\@collaborationImg{\@empty}
\def\@proceeding{\@empty}
\def\@preprint{\@empty}

\newcommand{\subheader}[1]{\gdef\@subheader{#1}}
\newcommand{\keywords}[1]{\if!\@keywords!\gdef\@keywords{#1}\else%
\PackageWarningNoLine{\jname}{Keywords already defined.\MessageBreak Ignoring last definition.}\fi}
\renewcommand{\abstract}[1]{\gdef\@abstract{#1}}
\newcommand{\dedicated}[1]{\gdef\@dedicated{#1}}
\newcommand{\arxivnumber}[1]{\gdef\@arxivnumber{#1}}
\newcommand{\proceeding}[1]{\gdef\@proceeding{#1}}
\newcommand{\xtumfont}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\newcommand{\correctionref}[3]{\gdef\@xtum{\xtumfont{#1} \href{#2}{#3}}}
\newcommand\jname{JHEP}
\newcommand\acknowledgments{\section*{Acknowledgments}}
\newcommand\notoc{\notoctrue}
\newcommand\preprint[1]{\gdef\@preprint{\hfill #1}}



%Equivalent to ``\footnote'', but can be used inside the \author macro
% because it does not write the footnote mark
% it has an optional argument that will be used as footnote mark when given
% WARNING: when the optional argument is used, the footnotecounter is not increased
% WARNING: the character ``!'' cannot be used.
% If you really need it use somthing like [\relax !] as the optional arg.
\newcommand\note[2][]{%
\if!#1!%
\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{#2}%
\else%
{\renewcommand\thefootnote{#1}%
\footnotetext{#2}}%
\fi}



%Use this if you want to try to keep some piece of the abstract on a
%very long first page
\newcommand\compress{%
\renewcommand\afterProceedingsSpace{\bigskip}%
\renewcommand\afterTitleSpace{\bigskip}%
\renewcommand\afterRuleSpace{\bigskip\bigskip}
\renewcommand\afterEmailSpace{\par\bigskip}}

%authors and affiliations
\newtoks\auth@toks
\renewcommand{\author}[2][]{%
  \if!#1!%
    \auth@toks=\expandafter{\the\auth@toks#2\ }%
  \else
    \auth@toks=\expandafter{\the\auth@toks#2$^{#1}$\ }%
  \fi
}

\newtoks\affil@toks\newif\ifaffil\affilfalse
\newcommand{\affiliation}[2][]{%
\affiltrue
  \if!#1!%
    \affil@toks=\expandafter{\the\affil@toks{\item[]#2}}%
  \else
    \affil@toks=\expandafter{\the\affil@toks{\item[$^{#1}$]#2}}%
  \fi
}

%emails
%automatically put a comma between emails
\newtoks\email@toks\newcounter{email@counter}%
\setcounter{email@counter}{0}%
\newcommand{\emailAdd}[1]{%
\emailaddtrue%
\ifnum\theemail@counter>0\email@toks=\expandafter{\the\email@toks, \@email{#1}}%
\else\email@toks=\expandafter{\the\email@toks\@email{#1}}%
\fi\stepcounter{email@counter}}
\newcommand{\@email}[1]{\href{mailto:#1}{\tt #1}}


% Collaboration macros
\newcommand*\collaboration[1]{\gdef\@collaboration{#1}}
\newcommand*\collaborationImg[2][]{\gdef\@collaborationImg{#2}}

%all pieces get a ``after'' spacing
\newcommand\afterLogoSpace{\smallskip}
\newcommand\afterSubheaderSpace{\vskip3pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\newcommand\afterProceedingsSpace{\vskip21pt plus0.4fil minus15pt}
\newcommand\afterTitleSpace{\vskip23pt plus0.06fil minus13pt}
\newcommand\afterRuleSpace{\vskip23pt plus0.06fil minus13pt}
\newcommand\afterCollaborationSpace{\vskip3pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\newcommand\afterCollaborationImgSpace{\vskip3pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\newcommand\afterAuthorSpace{\vskip5pt plus4pt minus4pt}
\newcommand\afterAffiliationSpace{\vskip3pt plus3pt}
\newcommand\afterEmailSpace{\vskip16pt plus9pt minus10pt\filbreak}
\newcommand\afterXtumSpace{\par\bigskip}
\newcommand\afterAbstractSpace{\vskip16pt plus9pt minus13pt}
\newcommand\afterKeywordsSpace{\vskip16pt plus9pt minus13pt}
\newcommand\afterArxivSpace{\vskip3pt plus0.01fil minus10pt}
\newcommand\afterDedicatedSpace{\vskip0pt plus0.01fil}
\newcommand\afterTocSpace{\bigskip\medskip}
\newcommand\afterTocRuleSpace{\bigskip\bigskip}
%this is the ``itemsep'' of the affiliations list
\newlength{\affiliationsSep}\setlength{\affiliationsSep}{-3pt}
%this hook is needed if the toc starts on the first page
\newcommand\beforetochook{\pagestyle{myplain}\pagenumbering{roman}}

\DeclareFixedFont\trfont{OT1}{phv}{b}{sc}{11}

%first page
\renewcommand\maketitle{
%% First page
\pagestyle{empty}
\thispagestyle{titlepage}
\setcounter{page}{0}
\noindent{\small\scshape\@fpheader}\@preprint\par
\afterLogoSpace
% Subheader
\if!\@subheader!\else\noindent{\trfont{\@subheader}}\fi
\afterSubheaderSpace
% Proceedings
\if!\@proceeding!\else\noindent{\sc\@proceeding}\fi
\afterProceedingsSpace
% Title
{\LARGE\flushleft\sffamily\bfseries\@title\par}
\afterTitleSpace
% Rule
\hrule height 1.5\p@%
\afterRuleSpace
% Collaboration
\if!\@collaboration!\else
{\Large\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright\@collaboration}\par
\afterCollaborationSpace
\fi
%
\if!\@collaborationImg!\else
{\normalsize\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright\@collaborationImg}\par
\afterCollaborationImgSpace
%% I leave the size and font so that if there are two collaboration
%% they can be linked with an 'and'
\fi
% Author
{\bfseries\raggedright\sffamily\the\auth@toks\par}
\afterAuthorSpace
% Affiliation
\ifaffil\begin{list}{}{%
\setlength{\leftmargin}{0.28cm}%
\setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\itemsep}{\affiliationsSep}%
\setlength{\topsep}{-\parskip}}
\itshape\small%
\the\affil@toks
\end{list}\fi
\afterAffiliationSpace
% E-mail
\ifemailadd %% if emailadd is true
\noindent\hspace{0.28cm}\begin{minipage}[l]{.9\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft}
\textit{E-mail:} \the\email@toks
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\else %% if emailaddfalse do nothing
\PackageWarningNoLine{\jname}{E-mails are missing.\MessageBreak Plese use \protect\emailAdd\space macro to provide e-mails.}
\fi
\afterEmailSpace
%Erratum or addendum
\if!\@xtum!\else\noindent{\@xtum}\afterXtumSpace\fi
% Abstract
\if!\@abstract!\else\noindent{\renewcommand\baselinestretch{.9}\textsc{Abstract:}}\ \@abstract\afterAbstractSpace\fi
% Keywords
\if!\@keywords!\else\noindent{\textsc{Keywords:}} \@keywords\afterKeywordsSpace\fi
% Arxivnumber
\if!\@arxivnumber!\else\noindent{\textsc{ArXiv ePrint:}} \href{https://arxiv.org/abs/\@arxivnumber}{\@arxivnumber}\afterArxivSpace\fi
% Dedication
\if!\@dedicated!\else\vbox{\small\it\raggedleft\@dedicated}\afterDedicatedSpace\fi
%
\ifnotoc\else
\iftoccontinuous\else\newpage\fi
\beforetochook\hrule
\tableofcontents
\afterTocSpace
\hrule
\afterTocRuleSpace
\fi
\setcounter{footnote}{0}
\pagestyle{myplain}\pagenumbering{arabic}
} % close the \renewcommand\maketitle{


% Page layout
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}\normalsize
\setlength\lineskip{1\p@}
\setlength\parindent{1.2\parindent}
\setlength\normallineskip{1\p@}
\setlength\parskip{0\p@ \@plus \p@}
\@lowpenalty   51
\@medpenalty  151
\@highpenalty 301
\widowpenalty 1000
\clubpenalty 1000

\setcounter{topnumber}{4}
\renewcommand\topfraction{1}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{1}
\renewcommand\bottomfraction{.6}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{5}
\renewcommand\textfraction{0}
\renewcommand\floatpagefraction{0.8}

\textwidth  .72\paperwidth
\setlength\@tempdima{.76\paperheight}
\divide\@tempdima\baselineskip
\@tempcnta=\@tempdima
\setlength\textheight{\@tempcnta\baselineskip}
\addtolength\textheight{\topskip}

\voffset -1in
\topmargin   .03\paperheight
\headheight  .01\paperheight
\headsep     .03\paperheight
\footskip    .11\paperheight

\marginparsep 9\p@
\marginparpush 6\p@

\hoffset -1in
\oddsidemargin .14\paperwidth
\evensidemargin .14\paperwidth
\marginparwidth .11\paperwidth

\setlength\arraycolsep{2\p@}
\setlength\tabcolsep{6\p@}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{.4\p@}
\setlength\doublerulesep{2\p@}
\setlength\tabbingsep{\labelsep}
\skip\@mpfootins = \skip\footins
\setlength\fboxsep{3\p@}
\setlength\fboxrule{.4\p@}

% No dots in the table of contents
\renewcommand{\@dotsep}{10000}

% Footer and header of the body
% the command ``\pagestyle{myplain}'' must be inserted
% just after ``\begin{document}''
\newcommand\ps@myplain{
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\renewcommand\@oddfoot{\hfill-- \thepage\ --\hfill}
\renewcommand\@oddhead{}}
\let\ps@plain=\ps@myplain



% no header or footer in the title page
\newcommand\ps@titlepage{\renewcommand\@oddfoot{}\renewcommand\@oddhead{}}



%number equations after the sections
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}


%headings style
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1.3ex \@minus -.7ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.4ex \@minus .4ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                   {-2.3ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.5ex}%
                                   {1.2ex \@plus .3ex \@minus .3ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                   {-2.3ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.5ex}%
                                   {1ex \@plus .2ex \@minus .2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                   {1.75ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                   {-1em}%
                                   {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\z@}%
                                   {1.75ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
                                   {-1em}%
                                   {\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}}


%Caption of figure and table
\def\fnum@figure{\textbf{\figurename\nobreakspace\thefigure}}
\def\fnum@table{\textbf{\tablename\nobreakspace\thetable}}

%redefining \@makecaption, to have captions with \small font size
%taken from article.cls l.489--498
%the only differences are the ``\small '' commands added on two lines
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \sbox\@tempboxa{\small #1. #2}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    \small #1. #2\par
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}





%apply some formatting on the biblio
%without redefining the whole env
\let\oldthebibliography=\thebibliography
\let\endoldthebibliography=\endthebibliography
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
\begin{oldthebibliography}{#1}%
\small%
\raggedright%
\setlength{\itemsep}{5pt plus 0.2ex minus 0.05ex}%
}%
{%
\end{oldthebibliography}%
}
```

Comment: don't change the page layout for a journal class, they are designed to fit their production process, not make manuscripts on A4 paper look good

Comment: yes but this looks very bad, so I want to modify to make the pdf good, not necessarity submitting

Comment: but it's the publisher's problem not the authors. If you change the layout the most likely outcome is that it won't get accepted. If  the textheight is set for the paper the journal uses, but you change it to look good on A4, the journal can not publish the article as it won't fit.

Comment: the space above the page number is `\footskip    .11\paperheight`  if you do want to change...

Comment: I tried to change this. It only makes the page number a bit down. But the text height is not changing

Comment: A quick suggestion: Use `\tfrac` instead of `\frac` in the two displayed equations, and maybe, just maybe, the three lines that are currently at the top of page 2 will fit at the bottom of page 1. :-)

Comment: Try updating the style file: https://jhep.sissa.it/jhep/help/JHEP/TeXclass/DOCS/jheppub.sty

Comment: @hair-splitter - The style file you provide a link to and the style file the OP posted would appear to be the same, i.e., same date and same version number.

Comment: @Mico The \footskip is different!

Comment: As a test, try loading the `showframe` package or placing `\hrule` under the last line on the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{jheppub} % https://jhep.sissa.it/jhep/help/JHEP/TeXclass/DOCS/jheppub.sty

\newlength{\oldfootskip}
\setlength{\oldfootskip}{\footskip}
\setlength{\footskip}{1cm}              % Set the new foot skip
\addtolength{\oldfootskip}{-\footskip}
\addtolength{\textheight}{\oldfootskip} % Appropriate increase the text height

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[-10]
\end{document}
```